# Where can I find lists of best games per tournament?

Tags: tournament, history, database, world-championship

I would like to obtain a list of best games per tournament (World Chess Championships, Chess World Cup, ...).

By "best" I mean games that either have won a brilliancy prize, or games that are considered by some other participants in the tournament as a best/most beautiful game.

Answer (score 1):

Chess Informant quarterly subscription gives you the best of games played in that quarter.

Or, The Week In Chess is the raw scores of games with no commentary and no qualifications.